# Can I set the VS Code default EOL based on file type?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Working with `.sh` files on Windows causes issues when running them in Linux Docker containers if they have EOL of CRLF. Can I make VS Code always work with LF for specific file type such as `.sh` while still using CRLF for all others?

I only find `"files.eol": "\r\n"` in settings, but this is global.

I understand you can change this in the bottom toolbar on a per-file basis, but I would like this to be the default for all `.sh` files.

Comment: You better use `LF` for all file types. Except for some stupid programs like Notepad, the programming and plain text editors on all OSes handle it as the newline character.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/).

Install the [editorconfig extension](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode), and then add a `.editorconfig` file at the root of your project with this:

```
[*]
end_of_line = crlf

[*.{sh}]
end_of_line = lf
```

But as @axiac said, I would recommend to always use `lf`...

Answer (score 20):

In your settings window, go to

`Settings > Text Editor > Files > Eol` option. You'll fine following available options there

```
- \n
- \r\n
- auto (default)
```

Here `\n` represents LF, `\r\n` represents CRLF, and `auto` use the operating system specific EL operator.

Select your option and save.

VS Code: version `1.13.3`

Comment: This does not answer the "based on file type" requirement. [This is still the issue on GitHub about this setting](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34876). (github (dot) com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34876)

Answer (score 11):

EDIT : I was a bit "premature" with this answer.  But it now works as of v1.40. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_40.md#fileseol-per-language

---

You can do this in vscode without an extension.  You can make a language-specific setting:

In the command palette, search for "`Configure language specific`", select it and choose "`shellscript`" from the language options:

This will create the following in your settings:

```
"[shellscript]": {

},
```

Now add in whatever you want to apply to shellscript files only like (not all settings will work in there but most do):

```
"[shellscript]": {
    "files.eol": "\n"
},
```

**VERY, VERY IMPORTANT**:

> The end-of-line sequence is used for new files. For existing files,
>   the existing end-of-line sequence is always preserved. To change the
>   end-of-line sequence for an existing file, use the Change End Of Line
>   Sequence command.

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_40.md#fileseol-per-language

Comment: This gives me the error "Unknown Identifier. Use language identifiers" and doesn't work. [There is an issue on GitHub to add this feature however.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34876)

Comment: You are correct - but it is coming now to v1.40.  How did I know?  LOL.